# Find a basis for $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb R^4$ where $x_2 + 2x_3 + 3x_4 = 0$

Tags: vector-spaces

In vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$ I'm supposed to find a basis for $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ with $x_2 + 2 x_3 + 3 x_4 = 0 $.

I'm not sure how to go about that. Thanks for help, I'd be especially thankful for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly, you have 4 variables and 1 constraint, so you expect to have 3 degrees of freedom.

Your constraint is $x_2+2 x_3 + 3 x_4 = 0$, or $x_2 = -(2 x_3 + 3 x_4)$. That is, if you specify $x_1,x_3,x_4$, then $x_2$ is given by this formula. To find a basis, set $(x_1,x_3,x_4)$ to each of the following $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ and compute the corresponding $x_2$. This gives
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$,
$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -2 \\1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$,
$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -3 \\0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

It is easy to see that these vectors are linearly independent and satisfy the constraint.  Furthermore, if $x$ is a vector that satisfies the constraint, then we can write $x =
x_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} +
x_3 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -2 \\1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} +
x_4 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -3 \\0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$,
and so these vectors form a basis for the space in question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I compared my results to wrong answer sheet, turns out my desperate tries were actually right.

To answer my own question:

1. x2=-2*x3-3*x4
2. we see that we don't have enough 'conditions', so we set free parameters:

x1=r
x2=-2*x3-3*x4
x3=s
x4=q

so we get: r*(1,0,0,0)+s*(0,-2,1,0)+q*(0,-3,0,1)

1. We have a base <(1,0,0,0),(0,-2,1,0),(0,-3,0,1)>